# Eraser effect in plane using shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to produce an eraser for a material on a plane.

The way I am thinking of doing this is by passing an array to the shader telling the shader where the material should be transparent; if the value from the array is 0, I return no color for the material (i.e. tranparent). I have 2 problems:

1. How do I declare and pass an array in CG?
2. Does this way work and if so, is this the best way to do this? I am thinking that it might be very demanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a Texture2D as your "array". That you can modify at run-time (Using [SetPixel](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html) or [SetPixels](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html)) and pass to a shader as you normally would.

And then in your shader you would appropriately manipulate your base texture using your "erased" texture. Manipulate alpha or so.

Given that you're dealing with a simple plane, that would seem like a fairly straightforward option.